# Why could data-mini and data-highlight not work in slider (jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple slider in jquery mobile

```
<label for="slider-1">Input slider:</label>
<input type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" value="60" min="0" max="100" data-highlight="true" data-theme="b" data-track-theme="b" data-mini="true"/>
```

The code is nearly copied and pasted from documentation (https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/forms/slider/) and the slider works. Value, data-theme, data-track-theme are fine and working. Instead, data-mini and data-highlight have no effect on the slider... Tried on different browsers, too. Why this could happen?

EDIT:
Tried the script way. No fortune too.

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#slider-1').slider({ mini: true });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/j0434dod/

Comment: I know, followed the documentation as I possibly could. I would be glad to publish some other code to show the issue, but I don't know which part could be causing this (partial!) issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Wrong library version

Changing

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc1/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc1/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

solved the problem